# what is the equivalent project file for a Java project?

Tags: java

What is the equivalent project file for a Java project?  For example, a C# project file is denoted by the delimiter of .csproj.  So what would it be for a Java project?  Is it dependent on what IDE I am using for Java?

I did some search online about this and it seems to me that the answer to this question is dependent on the IDE.  From memory, it seems to me, that all I have to do is drop the Java files into an IDE and then, somehow, a project file is automatically generated.  I do not want to be steered in the wrong direction on this and so I want to first ask around for guidance.

Comment: "Is it dependent on what IDE I am using for Java?"  Yes.  But "dropping Java files" into an IDE is probably the wrong approach.  A better approach is to use Maven or Gradle (or similar) build files, and then rely on the IDE's respective plugins to set up the project from what is in the build file, download dependencies + add them to the project, etc.

Answer (score 4):

You're probably looking for the build file, not the IDE project definition.

> Is it dependent on what IDE I am using for Java?

Yes. IntelliJ has `.iml` files, and Eclipse has `.project` (that's not a file ending - that's the file), as well as `.classpath`, `.factorypath`, and more. But, many of these are effectively generated or just refer to the build file. In C that tends to be called `Makefile`, in the Java ecosystem, Gradle and Maven are the 2 most popular build tools; they have **`build.gradle`** and **`pom.xml`** respectively. These would be more useful as basis for knowing how a project is 'put together', so to speak.

> From memory, it seems to me, that all I have to do is drop the Java files into an IDE and then, somehow, a project file is automatically generated.

That's *very* basic and should rarely work except for the simplest projects. For example, most Java projects have source files, test files (also source files but they are not part of the distribution), and resource files (non-Java files that are also needed for the app; think about the images for the icon on a button), as well as a ton of dependencies (third party libraries used by the Java app).

Given that folks like many IDEs, the IDE 'config file' is **not** what you are looking for, and many projects don't even check these into source control (and probably shouldn't). Together with the source, you have a build file. This build file knows how to download dependencies, compile every artifact (there doesn't have to be one; maybe there's the test code to the built, the main app, a plugin for some other tool, and an installer. Build tools can handle all that), run the tests and report on them, possibly even tell you about code coverage, and they usually *can* run the app, but more generally, you just want to tell the build tool to build a distributable for each relevant artifact.

Those build files are what you're looking for. With those you can build your project, *or* point an IDE at them and then you can edit the project with all the dependencies and classpath linkages all worked out for you.

Comment: Suggestion @ _Those build files are what you're looking for_ : It will be more clear if “build.gradle” and “pom.xml” are highlighted prominently at the very top of the answer (in a summary and details format)

Comment: Edited the answer a bit to highlight the notion that you probably want to look for the build files instead.